# <input> personalizado

Tags: javascript, html, html5, css

Tengo el siguiente código con el que quisiera emular la funcionalidad de este sitio: [Mathway](https://www.mathway.com/Algebra):

```css
.fraccion {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 .1em;
}
.denominador {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div style='border: 1px solid darkgray; width:200px' contenteditable spellcheck="false">
  hola
  <span class='fraccion'>
    <span>5</span>
  <span class='denominador'>
    <span>4</span>
  </span>
  </span>
  hola
</div>
```

Pero si quito el "hola" se queda el cursor en los números y no se posiciona en medio, si escribo algo se escribiría a lado del número.

¿Cómo paso el foco del cursor en medio (modo normal)?

Answer (score 3):

Yo usaría una función de javascript o jquery como gustes, en este caso como tu pregunta tiene la etiqueta jquery decidí hacer una función con jquery

una de las funciones que hice fue detectar el `click`

```
$('div').on('click',function(){
  //validación para agregar espacio al inicio solo si hay una función x/x
  if($(this).html().slice(0,1) == "<"){
    var text = $(this).html();
    var val = $(this).html("").append("&nbsp;" + text);
    //este es el segundo click pero no funciona
    setCursorToEnd($(this).get(0));
  }

  //Validación para agregar espacio al final solo di hay una función x/x
  if($(this).html().slice(-1) == ">"){
    var val = $(this).append("&nbsp;");
    //este es el segundo click pero no funciona
    setCursorToEnd($(this).get(0));
  }
});
```

Después fue posicionar el foco hasta el final basándome en esta [pregunta de SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13513329/6561804)

```
function setCursorToEnd(ele)
{
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(ele, 3);//cambiando 1 por 3 para dejar el cursor después del espacio.
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  ele.focus();
}
```

Tu código de ejemplo funcionando:

```js
$('div').on('click',function(){

  //validacion para agregar espacio al inicio solo si hay una funcion x/x
  if($(this).html().slice(0,1) == "<"){
    var text = $(this).html();
    var val = $(this).html("").append("&nbsp;" + text);
    //este es el segundo click pero no funciona
    setCursorToEnd($(this).get(0));
  }
  
  //Validacion para agregar espacio al final solo di hay una funcion x/x
  if($(this).html().slice(-1) == ">"){
    var val = $(this).append("&nbsp;");
    //este es el segundo click pero no funciona
    setCursorToEnd($(this).get(0));
  }
});


function setCursorToEnd(ele)
{
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(ele, 3);
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
  ele.focus();
}
```

```css
.fraccion
{
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 90%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 .1em;
}

.denominador
{
  border-top: 1px solid;
  float: right;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  style='border: 1px solid darkgray; width:200px' contenteditable>
  
  hola
  <span class='fraccion'>
    <span>5</span>
    
    <span class='denominador'>
      <span>4</span>
    </span>
  </span>
  
  hola
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para escribir fracciones debes usar las etiquetas de sup, sub te dejo un ejemplo

```html
<p contenteditable>6 <span class="fraccion"><sup>60</sup><span>/</span><sub>100</sub></‌span></p>
```

para hacerlo mas dinamico te dejo un ejemplo en cual consiste en insertar fraccion e insertar enteros con funciones.

```js
function insertarFraccion(){
  var sup=document.createElement('sup');
  var sub=document.createElement('sub');
  sup.id="numerador";
  var span=document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML="_";
  sup.appendChild(span);
  sub.id="denominador";
  var span2=document.createElement('span');
  span2.innerHTML="_";
  sub.appendChild(span2);
  var campo=document.getElementById("editable");
  campo.appendChild(sup);
  campo.appendChild(sub);
}
function insertarEntero(){

var span=document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML="_";
  var campo=document.getElementById("editable");
  campo.appendChild(span);
}
```

```css
#editable{
height:100px;
}


#numerador{border-bottom:solid black 1px; display:inline-block; float:left}
#denominador{ display:inline-block; clear:left; float:left}
```

```html
<p id="editable" contenteditable> </p>
<a href="#" onclick="insertarFraccion()">agregar fraccion</a>
<a href="#" onclick="insertarEntero()">agregar entero</a>
```

Aunque es un ejemplo con fallas, queria demostrar una mejor manera de lograr el objetivo.